# Why GCC does not support multithreading compile?

Tags: c, multithreading, gcc, makefile, compilation

AFAIK, Some part of C compilation phases can be multi-threaded.

For example, At least Preprocessing and Parsing (creating AST) is only related its source file itself so each file can be parallelized.

Is there any reason that GCC has no multi-threaded compile option?

Comment: Maybe because it is a piece of SW that is complex enough without adding multithreading to it and introducing all of the issues that will inevitably come? Anyway, translation units should be short enough to make a compilation of each of them fast enough. And using `gcc` as multiple processes to compile several TUs in parallel is widely done (`make -j`)

Comment: If what you are saying is true, my guess is that the programmers are simply lazy. But I think some third-party build/makefile systems maybe be able to achieve what you want.

Comment: @SvenNilsson: That is a very bad and uncharitable guess.

Comment: I agree; you won't get far in the free software community by accusing people of being "simply lazy" when they've worked for decades to bring you a COMPLETELY FREE and world-class compiler and all associated support software.  How about you write your own compiler to compete with GCC and add multithreading, then you can accuse people of being lazy and maybe someone will care.

Comment: That being said, there is work ongoing to add multithreading to GCC and binutils.  I think the primary focus is the linker where multithreading can be very helpful.  See for example https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/ParallelGcc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can build C/C++ in paralell if you use and setup a proper build system, which handles this for you.

Basically in C/C++ every .c/.cpp file is complied to an .o file. All these .o files are then linked to the resulting binary.

A build system (make for instance) can be used, to build all the .o files in paralell.

Comment: Oh, I didn't see that. That's the thing what I exactly said.